# Variable used before being initialized when I call my class

Tags: swift

I figure out a problem when I try to call a function in my class.

I get an error :

> Variable 'team' used before being initialized

I didn't understand why 'cause I respect the class initialization according to the two-phase process.

Teams.swift

```
class Team {
var number: Int
var personages: [CharacterC]
var playerName: String
var isOver: Bool {
    var numberOfDeadPersonages = 0
    for perso in personages where perso.isdead {
        numberOfDeadPersonages += 1
    }
    return numberOfDeadPersonages == personages.count
}

init(number: Int, personages: [CharacterC], playerName: String) {
    self.number = number
    self.personages = personages
    self.playerName = playerName
}

    func createTeams() {

    / Creation of each team /
    print("Let's get started, create the two teams which will compete")
    game = Game(team1: createNewTeam(number: 1), team2: createNewTeam(number: 2))

    / Creation of character of the team n°1 /
    print("\(game.team1.playerName), I'm pretty sure you can set up the best team let's figure it out")
    for personnageNumber in 1...3 {
        game.team1.personages.append(createNewPersonage(number: personnageNumber, inGame: game))
    }

    / Creation of character of the team n°2 /
    print("\(game.team2.playerName), use your advantage wisely, you can counter him")
    for personnageNumber in 1...3 {
        game.team2.personages.append(createNewPersonage(number: personnageNumber, inGame: game))
    }

    print("Now that the teams are set up, you're only goal is to defeat the ennemy team, good luck")
}
```

main.swift

```
var game: Game
var team: Team



createTeams()
gameOver()
```

Any idea guys ?

Comment: Please post the code as *text,* not as screenshots.

Comment: But the error message is quite clear: `var team` is nowhere initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You did declare `team`, but you didn't actually initialize it to a value. So, you cannot call any (non-static) function of `team` before initializing it:

```
var team = Team(number:..., personages:..., playerName:...)
team.createTeams()
```

(Replace `...` by whichever values you have)